# What is metrics.roc_curve and metrics.auc measuring when I'm comparing binary data with probability estimates?

Tags: logistic, python, auc

I was working on a challenge, and I was excited because the metric.auc for my predicted values compared to my test values was very high. This was for a binary selection process.

However, when I looked at it, my predicted values outputted by logistic regression were actually probabilities, not binary values.

So I rounded them, as the challenge requires binary predictions. When I rounded them, the auc score dropped drastically.

My understanding of the auc score and roc curve is that it compares false positives/negatives etc., and I don't even know how it came up with an actual value for these probabilistic predictions.

What was it computing before, and why was it so high?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you round up/down the predicted probabilities, you are essentially using 0.5 as a threshold for your classification. ROC curves do this not for one but **for every possible threshold**. The *false positive rates* and *true positive rates* are then plotted as roc curve (with the integral being the auc).

If the challenge requires you to provide binary predictions, they are unlikely to use AUC as performance measure.

Comment: Congrats on hitting 1000!

Comment: The $c$-index (concordance probability; area under ROC curve) is a decent pure measure of predictive discrimination when computed on the continuous probabilities and the binary outcomes.  But _proper accuracy scoring rules_ in this case are the Brier score and the pseudo $R^2$, which are more sensitive because they give more credit to extreme probabilities that are "right".